# Access, combine multiple query and update

Tags: sql, ms-access

The First update is:

```
UPDATE TABLE 1
INNER JOIN TABLE 2
ON (TABLE 1.Name      = TABLE 2.Name)
AND (TABLE 1.Location = TABLE 2.Location)
SET
  (
    TABLE 1.Address = TABLE 2.NewAddress
  )
WHERE (((TABLE 1.Name)= "Jack"));
```

The second update is:

```
UPDATE TABLE 1
SET TABLE 1.Locatio        = "NewYork"
WHERE (((TABLE 1.Location) = "GZ"
OR (TABLE 1.Location)      = "BJ")
AND ((TABLE 1.Name)        = "Jack"));
```

I want to use one query to combine these two update together, or any improvement on these two queries????

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need to combine the queries?

Comment: If you're just asking for feedback on your SQL, the proper site for that would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also, please don't introduce errors in your code while hiding the table names. `TABLE 1` should be `[TABLE 1]` or `TABLE_1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to combine those queries, you can do the following thing:

```
UPDATE TABLE 1
INNER JOIN TABLE 2
ON (TABLE 1.Name      = TABLE 2.Name)
AND (TABLE 1.Location = TABLE 2.Location)
SET
  (
    TABLE 1.Address = TABLE 2.NewAddress
    TABLE 1.Location = IIF((TABLE 1.Location = "GZ" OR TABLE 1.Location = "BJ"), "NewYork", TABLE 1.Location)
  )
WHERE (TABLE 1.Name= "Jack");
```